# SearchView not being focused properly after TabHost tab change

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I have a `SearchView` that is being always shown and a `TabHost` above as follows:

[image: SearchView on top ("žodis"), TabHost above ("English", "Lietuvių")]

I'm trying to keep `SearchView` focused on certain conditions by doing:

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

when I need focus. It seems to work fine.

However, if user switches tabs, refocusing `SearchBar` in `TabHost.OnTabChangeListener` doesn't seem to work properly - keyboard is still being shown as if `SearchView` was still focused, but the cursor on search view is gone and user can't type anything in. Tapping on a search view fixes things but I would like to do the "tap" myself instead of the user.

How do I re-focus search view properly?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @makovkastar yes, just posted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refocusing SearchView after a delay to allow the UI to finish updating (on mobile, sorry for brevity and typos):

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {   
    @Override public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        searchView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                searchView.setIconified(false);
                searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
            }
        }, 100);
    }
});
```